# Setting label's content from a different class

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net

I have a simple problem. **I want to change label's content from a different class but it doesn't happen**.

Here is my XML code:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Label Content="Imię:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="47,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <Label Content="Nazwisko:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="19,81,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbImie" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="87,52,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="tbNazwisko" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="87,83,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnDodaj" Content="Dodaj" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="233,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnWyswietl" Content="Wyświetl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="332,65,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75"/>
        <Label x:Name="labelOsoba" Content="a" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="82,189,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="27" Width="141"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is my MainWindow's code:

```
Class MainWindow

    Dim imie As String
    Dim nazwisko As String

    Dim osoba As Osoby = New Osoby()



    Private Sub btnDodaj_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnDodaj.Click
        imie = tbImie.Text
        nazwisko = tbNazwisko.Text
        osoba.dodajOsobe(imie, nazwisko)
    End Sub


    Private Sub btnWyswietl_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles btnWyswietl.Click
        osoba.wyswietlOsoby()
    End Sub
End Class
```

And here is my class where setting label doesn't work:

```
    Public Class Osoby

        Dim listaOsob As List(Of String)
        Dim glowneOkno As MainWindow


        Public Sub New()
            listaOsob = New List(Of String)
        End Sub


        Public Sub dodajOsobe(ByVal imie As String, ByVal nazwisko As String)
            listaOsob.Add(imie)
        End Sub


        Public Sub wyswietlOsoby()
            glowneOkno = New MainWindow()
            glowneOkno.labelOsoba.Content = listaOsob(0)  'here, it doesn't work
        End Sub

    End Class
```

PS. Sorry for polish names :)

Comment: Is this in Windows Forms? What exactly does 'it does not happen' mean; do you get no error but the content of the label doesn't change?

Comment: I use WPF. The content of the label doesn't change at all but I don't get any errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not updating the mainwindow object. Because You are creating new instance of your mainwindow object in second class. instead of that what you can do in Second class's constructor pass this Mainwindow object(already created) and in your function change the content of label it will surely work for you.

Solution

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public Mainwindow()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   Dim osoba As Osoby = New Osoby(this)

}
```

In second class

//now in constructor of second object

```
public void osoby(MainWindow obj)
{
  this.glowneOkno = obj;
}
```

As I am c# guy.Please convert it to respective vb using online tools.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I understand. I'm using c# too so this code is clear to me